The presence of "the" in the sentence of "Find all (the) indices of the ' ' character in a string"

Find all the indices of the ' ' characters in a string.
Find all indices of the ' ' characters in a string.

Do these two sentences have any difference?
Which one is it if one is more natural than the other and why?

Indices? Do you mean incidents, or occurrenes?

"find (the) indices of X", meaning finding the position of occurrences, is standard in technical documentation e.g. Mathworks.

The two sentences feel different to me, but it's hard to put my finger on what the difference is. I could imagine the first sentence as a comment in code, describing what's going on. Similarly, I could imagine the second sentence as an an assignment to a developer.
